# Dates Formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am having issues with a Formula. I have a table which has dates, going horizontal.

**Objective:**

I am trying to sum a row below if the date above is less than today. However i keep getting an error.

**Formula**

`=SUMIF(TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(CalendarYear,1,21),1),"aaa"),">"&today(),tblJanuary[@[1]:[31]])`

Answer (score 0):

Try
    `=SUMIF(A1:F1,"<"&TODAY(),A2:F2)`

=SUMIF(range of dates, criteria for date < today, range to sum)

[image]